# Where can I find the source code for ETH 2.0?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum

Where can I find the source code for ethereum 2.0 and what programming language is it written in. Also, will this source code be rewritten into another language?

And can I also run it and test it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list of the ETH 2.0 Beacon Chain client implementations can be found here: https://eth.wiki/eth2/clients

The source code for each can be found on the associated links.

Their corresponding languages are thus:

```
Client Name     Programming Language    License

Artemis         Java                    Apache 2.0
Firefly*        Go                      BSD-3-Clause
Harmony         Java                    GPLv3
Lighthouse      Rust                    GPLv2
Lodestar        JavaScript (TypeScript) GPLv3
Nimbus          Nim                     Apache 2.0 / MIT
Prysm           Go                      GPLv3
Shasper         Rust/Substrate          GPLv3
Trinity         Python                  MIT
Yeeth           Swift                   GPLv3
```

Before you copy/fork any of them, please note the licence conditions.

> And can I also run it and test it?

See the individual projects for instructions on how to install.